# Displaying backbone template in a new window

Tags: backbone.js

I need to open a backbone template in a new window.  Is this possible?  Currently I've got a template that is being displayed within a div but I need this content to display in a new window?  I thought using a route might be the way to go but I'm not sure.

I'm a noob to backbone so there's probably a better way to do this.

In my view I've got:

```
events: 
{
  'click #active-bets' : 'loadActiveBetsPage',
}

loadActiveBetsPage: function(e)
{
  var MyApp = new Backbone.Router();
  MyApp.navigate('activebets', {trigger: true}); 
  //  , {trigger: true, target: "_blank"}
},
```

I thought I might get lucky and be able to pass a target: "_blank" parameter here.

in my routes sections:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    ":activebets" : "renderActiveBets",
    "*actions"      : "defaultRoute"
} });


    app_router.on('route:renderActiveBets', function () {
        $this.activeBetsView = new ActiveBetsView( { el: $this.elAccountInfo });
        $this.activeBetsView.render();

        /* thought something like this might help possibly
        if ($(event.currentTarget).prop('target') === '_blank') {
         return true;
        }
        */

    });`
```

Thank you in advance for any help on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible and especially not with the Backbone Router directly.

The only ways to open new browser windows from a webpage are using the [`window.open` javascript method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp). It will open a new browser window that directs to the URL specified. Note that the the page you have created and the page you started at are independent of each other and there is no way to communicate between them via javascript.

The other way is to have an anchor tag with the [`target` -attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp), which results in clicking the link opening a new window/tab.

What you can do:

1. Use a dialog created with html to simulate a new window, e.g. [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)
2. Create a separate webpage to display this information, open a new browser window and direct the new window to this webpage.

Comment: window.open('/help','_blank') works onclick but its not working on right click

Answer (score 0):

Update based on last comment:

> "...there is no way to communicate between them via javascript."

Since HTML5, the solution for this is HTML5 Web Storage.

```
window.localStorage
```

is API that can communicate with all open tabs and windows in browser.